# FAQ boxes of my website aren't working well?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to build this kind of FAQ question boxes in my website:

If I click on "plus" icon or text, they won't be open. Therfore I think, there may be some errors in JavScript code.

[image]

These are codes of the FAQ boxes in HTML, CSS & JavaScript:

[But they are not working well]

```js
// Showing/hiding FAQS answers

const faqs = document.querySelectorAll('.faq');

faqs.forEach(faq => {
  faq.addEventListener('click', () => {
    faq.classList.toggle('open');

    // Changing icon
    const icon = faq.querySelector('.faq__icon i');
    if (icon.className === 'uil uil-plus') {
      icon.className = "uil uil-minus"
    } else {
      icon.className = "uil uil-plus"
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.faq {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.4rem;
  height: fit-content;
  background: var(--color-primary);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faq h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.faq__icon {
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.faq p {
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
  display: none;
}

.faq.open p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article class="faq">
  <div class="faq__icon"><i class="uil uil-plus"></i></div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum ?</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente odio natus excepturi, culpa rem deleniti? Cum pariatur aut nulla a recusandae sit itaque voluptatem optio! Possimus, iure! Mollitia, voluptatum?</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

I do not know how to do this; can you help me, please?

Comment: Look at the console for any errors, please add 'whats' not working.

Comment: you don't have any CSS that give the classes `.uil .uil-plus`, `.uil .uil-minus` any styling

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I looked at console, but there is not any error. And I added in the question what is not working. It is FAQ boxes. There are the pictures of that FAQ boxes aren't working in the question.

Comment: Because I took this classes `.uil .uil-plus`, `.uil .uil-minus` from Iconscout CDN.

Comment: You need to specify what is not working for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I specified what is not working !!!

Comment: Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please help me to fix this ?!